# How to sign a transaction with keypair?

Tags: anchor, testing, anchor-test

I'm working on pda's and I have this code:

```
    #[derive(Accounts)]
    #[instruction(user_name: String , phone_number: String , email: String)]
    pub struct CreateUserAccount<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    // space: 8 discriminator + 2 level + 4 name length + 200 name + 1 bump
    #[account(
    init,
    payer = user,
    space = 8 + 2 + 4 + 200 + 1,    seeds = [b"user-account".as_ref(),user.key().as_ref() ,user_name.as_bytes() , email.as_bytes() , phone_number.as_bytes()   ],bump,

)]            
pub user_stats: Account<'info, UserAccount>,
pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

And this test:

```
it('First User', async () => {

const [userAccountPDA, _] = await PublicKey
  .findProgramAddress(
      [
        anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("user-account"),
        provider.wallet.publicKey.toBuffer(),
        anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("reasje"),
        anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("09144568517"),
        anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode(""),
      ],
      program.programId
  );

await program.methods
  .createUserAccount("reasje", "09144568517", "")
  .accounts({
    user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
    userStats: userAccountPDA,
  })
  .rpc();

expect((await program.account.userAccount.fetch(userAccountPDA)).userName).to.equal("reasje");
});

it('Second user', async () => {

const [userAccountPDA2, __] = await PublicKey
.findProgramAddress(
    [
      anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("user-account"),
      provider.wallet.publicKey.toBuffer(),
      anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("reasje"),
      anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("091445685177"),
      anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode(""),
    ],
    program.programId
);

await program.methods
.createUserAccount("reasje", "091445685177", "")
.accounts({
  user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
  userStats: userAccountPDA2,
})
.rpc();

expect((await program.account.userAccount.fetch(userAccountPDA2)).userName).to.equal("reasje");

});
```

I have trouble making the second user because only signer I have is the provider.wallet.publicKey and so both users are created with one Keypair, How can i generate a new Keypair which is able to sign a transaction with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add signers like this as well as system program since you are creating a new account:

```
await program.methods
.createUserAccount("reasje", "091445685177", "")
.accounts({
  user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
  userStats: userAccountPDA2,
  systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
})
.signers([provider.wallet])
.rpc()
```

You need to ensure that your main account specified in the `anchor.toml` also has a balance. If you are intiliasing non-PDA, you also need to include that keypair in the signers array.

To create test accounts for testing you can do:

```
  const LAMPORTS_PER_SOL = 1000000000    
  const acc1 = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

      await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(
        await provider.connection.requestAirdrop(
          acc1.publicKey,
          2 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL // 2 SOL top-up
        )
      );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how come the `provider.wallet.publicKey` works without `.signer([])` but not the Keypairs ?  I mean I'm confused between the `Signer` & `signers([])`.

Comment: I don't think it is explained anywhere, but you always implicitly sign with `provider.wallet` which is the default account used for deployment.

Comment: Beat me to it! Relevant source code: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/ts/src/provider.ts#L140

Answer (score 1):

@mega_creamery's answer works well, but I also want to add that you can simulate users on your front end by creating a "Program" with their "wallet" address:

```
  let wallet: Keypair = Keypair.generate();
  const userProgram = new Program(
    program.idl,
    program.programId,
    new AnchorProvider(program.provider.connection, new Wallet(wallet), {})
  );
```

Now you can sign "user" transactions by sending them as userProgram.provider, since the provider always signs the tx. Note that the wallet needs to be funded with some lamports for tx fees:

```
  const fundTx = new Transaction().add(
    SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey, // the default program wallet
      toPubkey: userWallet.publicKey, // user's wallet
      lamports: 1000 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
    })
  );
  await provider.sendAndConfirm(fundTx, [wallet.payer]);
```